# Npgsql Throws an Error if Parameter Comes after IS

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am attempting to use Npgsql to query for rows with a NULL value, and using a simple query it works, but it error if I use a prepared statement.

For example, this query would work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS NULL LIMIT 10;
```

But this one wouldn't:

```
// @null is a parameter with a null value (DBNull.Value)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS @null LIMIT 10;
```

This query would return an empty result set but no errors which is expected:

```
// @null is a parameter with a null value (DBNull.Value)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = @null LIMIT 10;
```

I also tried using IS for a boolean value and again it behaved as was expected using =, but threw an error on IS. Am I doing something incorrectly or is this a bug?

Stack trace/error info:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException -- External component has thrown an exception.
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.Prepare()
```

All tests were run using version 3.0.4 originally as well as 3.1.9.

Comment: IS alone is meaningless?

Comment: = alone is also meaningless. = \@param is not. IS \@param also is not.

Comment: I mean. IS NULL is a whole statement as IS FALSE or IS TRUE. You cannot break apart and use only the IS part and stick a parameter to complete the statement.

Comment: Oh I see. So essentially NULL parameter values are worthless? Except for inserts and function parameters I suppose. @Steve

Comment: NULL parameter values are definitely not worthless - you can use them, for example, when inserting values (which are sometimes null and sometimes aren't). However, as stated above IS NULL is an expression you can't break apart - parameters aren't a textual search-and-replace.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying. If you submit an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments `IS` and `IS NOT` are not terms that can be used alone. They are parts of a greater statement: `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` that cannot be broken apart.